# Flutter: shrink container inside Wrap if space

Tags: flutter

I have the following Wrap

```
Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Wrap(children: [
                    AboutImage(),
                    AboutText(),
                  ],),
                  Availability()
                ],
              ),
```

`AboutImage` and `Availability` have fixed width.

When resizing the screen I would like `AboutText` to shrink up until a certain minimum width so to let `Availability` stay up right as much as possible before going into the next row.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Please share desired output snippet and expected output snippet

Comment: ConstraintBox should be useful here.